# Ajax Rendered Html Input is not getting submitted in Post Request

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, formcollection

```
<select class="select2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Filtre Seçiniz..." id="Yazarlist" multiple="" name="Yazarlist" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="3">Ahmet Test 2</option>
<option value="4">Ahmet Test 3</option>
</select>
```

This is what i rendering using ajax by this code:

```
success: function (response) {
            var responseString = "";
            for (i in response) {
                responseString += "<option value='" + response[i].Value + "'>" + response[i].Text + "</option>";
            }
            $('#Yazarlist').html(responseString);
        }
```

When i View page source i get this:

```
<select class="select2 form-control" data-placeholder="Filtre Seçiniz..." id="Yazarlist" multiple="multiple" name="Yazarlist"></select>
```

So When i select the thing in this multiselect input i get nothing in FormCollection in my ActionMethod

Comment: This input element is not a part of my model used in view.i want to get this in FormCollection

Answer (score 0):

try

$('#Yazarlist').append(responseString);

in your ajax